# My react-native project brakes after installing react-native-image-picker but it works fine if i uninstall it

Tags: react-native, imagepicker, react-native-image-picker

My React Native project brakes after installing `react-native-image-picker` but it works fine if I uninstall it.

It brakes with this error message.

```
import undefined.ImagePickerPackage;
                ^
C:\Users\uchen\Documents\My Company\Afriguest\frontend\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:8
6: error: cannot find symbol
      new ImagePickerPackage(),
          ^
  symbol:   class ImagePickerPackage
  location: class PackageList`
```

I have tried manual linking even though its react-native v68 and it still didnt work. but the app runs well if I uninstall it.

Comment: Did you run pod install after installing?